# how to configure datefield xtype in dialog to just show list of years for selection instead of m/d/Y in aem

Tags: aem

how to configure datefield xtype in dialog to just show list of years for selection instead of m/d/Y in aem.
[image: m/d/Y]
I tried to configure it using the format property, and was able to just get the year when i select any date from datefield.
[image] 
Is there a way to just show the years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calendar xtype does not expose any method or property to suppress the display of month and day. This is because the control returns a full date which must contain a day, month and year value.

Assuming your business logic dictates some upper or lower bound for year, i.e. 2017 means 1 Jan 2017 or 31 Dec 2017, then you are better off using a drop down list for year selection and saving the value in correct data type in accordance to your business requirement.